# inverse reshape in matlab

Tags: matlab, reshape

I have used the function `reshape()` to help change sizes from a 3D matrix to a 2D one. Eg :

```
a = [1 2; 3 4];
b = [5 6; 7 8];
c = cat(3,a,b);
```

Here `c` is the matrix with 3 dimensions. I used `reshape` to change it thus:

```
[n,m,d] = size(c);
d = reshape(c, [n*m , d]);
```

The size of `d` is 4x2.

After this operation, how do I get back `c` from `d`? What I would like to know is the inverse of the `reshape` function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modifying your notations (you have 2 `d`):

```
a = [1 2; 3 4];
b = [5 6; 7 8];
c = cat(3,a,b);
[n,m,d] = size(c);
dd = reshape(c, [n*m , d]);
cc = reshape(dd, [n, m , d]);
```

and you can check that `cc` is equal to `c`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you overwrote the depth of the array `d` to be the reshaped array. Try:

```
[n,m,p] = size(c);
d = reshape(c, [n*m , p]);
reshape(d,[n m p])
```

Result:

```
ans(:,:,1) =

     1     2
     3     4


ans(:,:,2) =

     5     6
     7     8
```